# Adding .env file to other directories instead of root

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

A common practice is to add all .env files in root directory. However when dealing with different statuses of projects i.e. development, integration, production etc. it creates a mess at the root.

I was wondering if it is acceptable and industry practice to add all configuration files in config folder, or any other folder for that matter. Something like this

```
root
  |--.nvmrc
  |--.gitignore
  |--package.json
  |--package-lock.json
  |--src
       |--config
          |-- .env.development
          |-- .env.production
          |-- .env.integration
       |--utils
       |--server.js
```

Comment: Unfortunately, from what I've seen, this doesn't seem to be a common practice. Although it will help clean up your local repository and you can use packages like config to point to them, the pathing may interfere with CI/CD.

Comment: And?! Whats your problem? There speaks nothing against to put the files where you want. The "problem" is, that you need to tell your application where to find these. That you didnt say anything about how you load these, i cant help you there. But to answer your specific question: Fell free to move them where ever you want.

Comment: @Marc No problem as such, just needed to know if this practice actually has any advantage. Of course, I can use the various package to point to it and load these. It is more of a clean code type of question.

Comment: @VivekKumar it really doesn't matter where you put them, some frameworks might have a definition of where it must be placed and you will have to follow it, e.g ruby on rails places it in the configs/environments folder, create-react-app places it in the root, so let's assume you are setting up the project from scratch, so you are left to make the architectural decisions. But IMO, it's not worth the hassle just put the thing in the root dir.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on same question, and agree with responses in comments, i.e., not sure about industry standard.

But this works as solution.

```js
// config/index.js - basically this file should be in same folder where all .env.<environment> files are there.
// or, give exact path instead of `__dirname`

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "dev";
dotenv.config({ path: path.join(__dirname, `.env.${env}`) });
```